# pl/sql control structure getting error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Que
Use control Structure to write a program to display the credit limit of customers. The user should be asked to enter the Customer id. And according to their credit limit one of the following messages should be displayed. The last message will be displayed in case of employees whose Credit limit is greater than $4500.

what is wrong with this code please reply

```
     declare         
 v_emp_id employees.employee_id%type;           
     v_cust_num customers.customers#%type;       
      v_creditlimit customers.creditlimit%type;             

      begin 
        select employee_id ,customer# into v_emp_id ,    
        v_cust_num from employees natural join customers      
        where v_emp_id = '&v_emp_id';               

     if v_creditlimit < 1000 then      
     dbms_output.put_line ('credit limit less than 1000');        
        elseif v_creditlimit< 2000 then      
        dbms_output.put_line ('credit limit less than 2000');        
          elseif v_creditlimit< 3000 then       
          dbms_output.put_line ('credit limit less than 3000');        
        elseif v_creditlimit< 4000 then          
        dbms_output.put_line ('credit limit less than 4000');      
        elseif v_creditlimit< 6000 then      
        dbms_output.put_line ('credit limit less than 6000');             
       end if;       
    end;          
    /
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Don't use `NATURAL JOIN`. Make it easy on those who come after you (or those who are trying to help you) and clearly specify your join criteria. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to start with **v_creditlimit** is not initialized or assigned to any value in your query second thing v_emp_id is a variable that you declared and you are using it as a field for table

Try the code below

```
    create table customers1 (customers# int,creditlimit int,employee_id int);

select * from customers1;

begin
insert into customers1 values(11,123,1);
insert into customers1 values(12,345,2);
commit;
end;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
create table employees(employee_id int, first_name varchar2(20), last_name varchar2(20));

select * from employees;

begin
insert into employees values(1,'a','b');
insert into employees values(2,'c','d');
insert into employees values(3,'e','f');
commit;
end;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE
  v_emp_id employees.employee_id%type;
  v_cust_num customers1.customers#%type;
  v_creditlimit customers1.creditlimit%type;
BEGIN

  dbms_output.put_line('Enter the employee id.');
  v_emp_id := &emp_id;

  SELECT customers# INTO v_cust_num
  FROM employees NATURAL JOIN customers1 WHERE employee_id = v_emp_id;

  SELECT creditlimit into v_creditlimit
  FROM employees NATURAL JOIN customers1 WHERE employee_id = v_emp_id;

 dbms_output.put_line(v_cust_num); 
 dbms_output.put_line(v_creditlimit);

   IF v_creditlimit < 1000 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line ('credit limit less than 1000');
  elsif v_creditlimit BETWEEN 1001 and 2000 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line ('credit limit BETWEEN 1001 and 2000');
  elsif v_creditlimit BETWEEN 2001 and 3000 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line ('credit limit BETWEEN 2001 and 3000');
  elsif v_creditlimit BETWEEN 3001 and 4000 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line ('credit limit BETWEEN 3001 and 4000');
  elsif v_creditlimit BETWEEN 5001 and 6000 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line ('credit limit BETWEEN 5001 and 6000');
  END IF;

END;
```